# How to ignore statements throwing NullPointerException in java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nodes

I have a linked list like structure of Node objects.

```
class Node {
    int key;
    Node prev;   //previous Node
    Node next;   //next Node
}
```

Now, to delete a node N of this chain, there are four cases, N.prev being null, N.next being null, both of them being null or neither of them. It leads to four checks in code.

```
void delete(Node N) {
    Node Prev = N.prev;
    Node Next = N.next;

    //Case: N is the only node in list
    if (Prev == null && Next == null) {
        TreeHead = null;          //Treehead is the first Node of list
    }
    //Case: N is the starting node
    else if (Prev == null) {
        Next.prev = null;
        TreeHead = n;
    }
    //Case: N is the last node
    else if (Next == null) {
        Prev.next = null;
    }
    //Case: N is neither first nor last
    else {
        Prev.next = Next;
        Next.prev = Prev;
    }
}
```

This seems like inefficient code. I can write it like this(see below), but it will throw NullPointerException when an property of null object is accessed. I want to just ignore the statement if the object is null and move onto next line. How should i go about this?

```
static void delete(Node N) {
    Node Prev = N.prev;
    Node Next = N.next;

    if(Next == null && Prev == null) {TreeHead = null;return;}
    Prev.next = Next;
    Next.prev = Prev;
    //if Next becomes the starting node
    if(Next.prev == null) TreeHead = Next;
}
```

Comment: If something throws a `NullPointerException`, don't ignore it: fix it.

Comment: The code with all the null checks is verbose, but it's not inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

> How should i go about this?

Don't. Just don't. Ignoring (or attempting to ignore) exceptions is not a good practice.

> This seems like inefficient code.

It's not. Checking if something is null is *vastly* more efficient than creating a `NullPointerException`.

Consider that creating an exception requires the JVM to walk all the way back up the stack to create the stack trace; compare that to a single bytecode instruction to check if a thing is null.

Answer (score -3):

NullPointerExceptions must be fixed.
Use Optional from Java 8 to effectively handle such situations.